# In VBA, is the syntax different when creating an object vs. not?

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies, this was difficult to word as a clear question.

The following line is valid:

```
objWord.Documents.Add Template:=templatePath
```

But this line is not:

```
Set objMergedReq = objWord.Documents.Add Template:=templatePath
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Expected: end of statement
```

Why are the two interpreted differently? How do I eliminate the error? Do I need extra parentheses in case 2?

Comment: you need to use parenthesis when setting, so `set x=f(y)`

Answer (score 3):

The crux is this:

```
objWord.Documents.Add Template:=templatePath
```

This is a function call, but the returned value (an object reference) is discarded and thus, the function is really used as if it were a procedure; with VBA's *implicit* procedure call syntax, parentheses are not present. You can use the [deprecated] *explicit* call syntax to require the parentheses:

```
Call objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=templatePath)
```

As you noticed, this is illegal:

```
Set objMergedReq = objWord.Documents.Add Template:=templatePath
```

Because the syntax for a *function call* (you're not discarding the returned value here) requires the parentheses whenever an argument list is specified:

```
Set objMergedReq = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=templatePath)
```

If you're tempted to "just use parentheses everywhere", know that you'll run into other syntax issues, as soon as you need to specify 2 or more arguments:

```
MsgBox (message, vbOkOnly + vbInformation) 'illegal
```

That's because when arguments are surrounded by parentheses, you're really telling VBA to *evaluate the contents of the parentheses as a value*, and pass the result `ByVal` to the function/procedure, *even if that function/procedure is explicitly specifying the parameter as `ByRef`*.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use parenthesis when setting, so `set x=f(y)`

Comment: Thanks. That did it...
Set objMergedReq = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=templatePath)

Answer (score 2):

When there is no return value, like when you use a Sub, or you ignore the return value, you don't put the parameters in parenthesis. Optionally, you can use "Call" and then put the parameters in parenthesis.

In your example,

```
objWord.Documents.Add Template:=templatePath
```

the add method does create a return value, but you are not using it. Therefore, you either don't use parentheses (as you show), or you could use the "Call" statement:

```
Call objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=templatePath)
```

In your second example, you are using the return value, so parenthesis are required:

```
Set objMergedReq = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=templatePath)
```

The "Set" is needed because you are assigning an object. The same rules apply if the return value is a non object -- you would just omit the "Set".